# Angular 16 - angular-material-components/datetime-picker

Tags: angular

I'm updating my Angular Application from 14 to 16.
Unfortunally it seems like @angular-material-components/datetime-picker is only compatible to 15 with version 9.0.

When trying to install the library, I got this error:

```
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/cdk@15.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@"^15.0.1" from @angular-material-components/datetime-picker@9.0.0
```

I've tryed using --force and the installation goes on but I prefer a stable solution.
The npm page is freezed to 7 months ago.
I cant find any post regarding this problem or any advice to replace this library.

Comment: See https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/324

Comment: Seems like I not the only one -_-

Answer (score -1):

According to [Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) it is supported at 16. I've always found upgrading Angular painful. I would first ensure you are on the latest version of Node. Then update all the Angular components, then Material followed by any other 3rd party components. Dont forget you may have to use the Global flag for some of your components.

Comment: The question is not about @angular/material (which does not have a date-time picker)

Comment: @TmTron yes it is, it's the first part of the question. EviSvil states that it only goes to v15 and it does not. I think he meant date-picker

Comment: What part do you refer to? I only see `angular-material-components/datetimepicker` (https://h2qutc.github.io/angular-material-components/datetimepicker) and not a single mention of `@angular/material` (except in your answer).